# How to convert callback based API into one based on Observable?

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java

The library I'm using emits a series of `Message` objects using callback object.

```
interface MessageCallback {
    onMessage(Message message);
}
```

The callback is added using some `libraryObject.setCallback(MessageCallback)` call and the process is started using non-blocking `libraryObject.start()` method call.

What is the best way of creating an `Observable<Message>` that will emit those objects?

What if the `libraryObject.start()` is blocking?

Comment: Don't do this. Nobody uses `Observable.` There is no benefit in this change. Leave it alone.

Comment: I hoped using rx.Observable would make it easier down the road to mix and match multiple asynchronous data sources/sinks

Comment: It will make it harder. Why spend the time? The money?

Comment: @EJP care to elaborate on that claim? IMO the compositional nature of Observable makes it *a lot easier* to work with multiple asynchronous streams.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552598/creating-observable-from-normal-java-events/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this (example given in scala)

```scala
import rx.lang.scala.{Observable, Subscriber}

case class Message(message: String)

trait MessageCallback {
  def onMessage(message: Message)
}

object LibraryObject {
  def setCallback(callback: MessageCallback): Unit = {
    ???
  }

  def removeCallback(callback: MessageCallback): Unit = {
    ???
  }

  def start(): Unit = {
    ???
  }
}

def messagesSource: Observable[Message] =
  Observable((subscriber: Subscriber[Message]) ⇒ {
    val callback = new MessageCallback {
      def onMessage(message: Message) {
        subscriber.onNext(message)
      }
    }
    LibraryObject.setCallback(callback)
    subscriber.add {
      LibraryObject.removeCallback(callback)
    }
  })
```

As for the blocking/non-blocking `start()`: Usually callback-based architecture separates callback subscription and the process start. In that case, you can create as many `messageSource`s as you want completely independently of when you `start()` the process. Also the decision whether you fork it or not is completely upon you. Is your architecture different from this?

You should also handle finishing the process somehow. The best would be to add an `onCompleted` handler to the MessageCallback interface. If you want to handle errors, also add an `onError` handler. Now behold, you have just declared the fundamental building stone of RxJava, an [Observer](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/index.html?rx/Observer.html) :-)

Comment: what if the `MessageCallback` interface has multiple methods, how to convert it into a single observable? there can be only one `onNext` method and only one parameter

Answer (score 6):

### 1. Callback invoked infinite number of times

We can convert it to Observable like this (example for RxJava 2):

```
Observable<Message> source = Observable.create(emitter -> {
        MessageCallback callback = message -> emitter.onNext(message);
        libraryObject.setCallback(callback);
        Schedulers.io().scheduleDirect(libraryObject::start);
        emitter.setCancellable(() -> libraryObject.removeCallback(callback));
    })
    .share(); // make it hot
```

`share` makes this observable *hot*, i.e. multiple subscribers will share single subscription, i.e. there will be at most one callback registered with `libraryObject`.

I used `io` scheduler to schedule `start` call to be made from background thread, so it does not delay first subscription.

### 2. Single message callback

It is quite common scenario as well. Let's say we have the following callback-style asynchronous method:

```
libraryObject.requestDataAsync(Some parameters, MessageCallback callback);
```

Then we can convert it to Observable like this (example for RxJava 2):

```
Observable<Message> makeRequest(parameters) {
    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        libraryObject.requestDataAsync(parameters, message -> {
            emitter.onNext(message);
            emitter.onComplete();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get my head around RxJava, coming from RxJS. This is getting towards something I would like to know. How can you wrap an observable round an API which requires a value to be returned to it? In RxJS, you would use fromEventPattern and a wrapper function, I can't find the equivalent in RxJava,