# Converting callback which will be invoked infinite number of times to Observable

Tags: android, rx-java

Lets say I have a callback which will be invoked infinite number of times

`public interface Callback{
     void onPreview(byte[] data);
}`

but I need to set it earlier in `camera.setPreviewCallback(Callback cb);`

How to proper handle this situation with RxJava? I want to get data from this stream asynchronously especially when I finish my job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert callback based API into one based on Observable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040346/how-to-convert-callback-based-api-into-one-based-on-observable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Observable.fromEmitter` and set `camera.setPreviewCallback(Callback cb)` from the body of `Observable.fromEmitter`

```
 public void stuff() {
       Observable<Byte[]> obs = Observable.fromEmitter(emitter -> {
              Callback cb = bytes -> emitter.onNext(bytes);
              camera.setPreviewCallback(cb);
       }

       obs.subscribe(bytes -> /* perform with bytes */);

 }
```

(java 8 syntax is used only for clarity / ie: you can build an anonymous class instead of a lambda)

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you should have a method `camera.getPreview()` that returns an Observable which emit byte arrays. So the camera does not callback a handler, but returns an Observable the caller can subscribe upon.