# Android. How to handle events with debounce?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java2, debouncing

I'm using library and handle event from library (for example `onUpgrade`). The problem is that this event can be called very often, therefore I need handle my `onUpgrade` event with debounce 3 seconds.
Please help me how can this be done? I used already Rx java debounce, but with edit text, and  I don't understand how it can be applied to an event `onUpgrade`  from the library.

```
onUpgrage: (Data) -> Unit
```

Comment: Without code it would be difficult to offer the solution. I assume your ```onUpgrade``` calls are not wrapped as ```Observable``` objects, also it is not clear how do you process this data next. You might create data member field, update on your ```onUpgrade``` call, but read this data from other parts of your application by wrapping it into ```Observable``` object, e.g. https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/just.html

Comment: Convert the callback to an Observable using `Observable.create()`. Then you can use `debounce()` on it. https://github.com/mgp/effective-rxjava/blob/master/items/convert-callbacks-to-observable.md https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118782/replace-callbacks-with-observables-from-rxjava