# Rx Java Android : How to convert this callback block to Observer

Tags: callback, rx-java, rx-android

I'm trying to upload a file via Amazon's S3 Android SDK. I've used RX Java a bit but I'm not sure how to convert this method to a method that returns an Observable because I want to chain the result of this method to another Observable call. It confuses me I suppose because of the fact that this does not return right away and can't return until either OnError or OnState changes. How do I handle these situations in an RX way?

```
public void uploadFile(TransferObserver transferObserver){

    transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {

        }
  });

}
```

If someone could answer with RX Java 2 and lambdas that would be great because I just keep coming up short on this one

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41870888/697313

Answer (score 1):

This is generally the right approach to bridge between the async/callback workd to reactive, but using `Observable.create()` is now discouraged, as it's requires advanced knowledge in order to make it right.
You should use more recent create method `Observable.fromEmitter()`, which will look quite the same:

```
    return Observable.fromEmitter(new Action1<Emitter<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Emitter<Integer> emitter) {

            transObs.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                    if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED)
                        emitter.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                    emitter.onError(ex);
                }
            });
            emitter.setCancellation(new Cancellable() {
                @Override
                public void cancel() throws Exception {
                    // Deal with unsubscription:
                    // 1. unregister the listener to avoid memory leak
                    // 2. cancel the upload 
                }
            });
        }
    }, Emitter.BackpressureMode.DROP);
```

What was added here is: dealing with unsusbcription: cancelling the upload, and unregistering to avoid memory leaks, and specifying backpressure strategy.
you can read more [here](https://medium.com/yammer-engineering/converting-callback-async-calls-to-rxjava-ebc68bde5831).

additional notes:

- if you interested with progress you can call onNext() with progress at `onProgressChanged()` and convert the Observable to `Observable<Integer>`.
- if not, you might want to consider using `Completable` which is Observable with no `onNext()` emissions but only `onCompleted()` this can suits your case if your not interested with progress indications.

Answer (score 0):

@Yosriz I could not get your code to compile , but you did help me quite a bit so based on your answer here is what I now have:

```
return Observable.fromEmitter(new Action1<AsyncEmitter<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(AsyncEmitter<Integer> emitter) {

                transObs.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                        if (state == TransferState.COMPLETED)
                            emitter.onCompleted();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                        emitter.onError(ex);
                    }
                });

                emitter.setCancellation(new AsyncEmitter.Cancellable() {
                    @Override
                    public void cancel() throws Exception {

                        transObs.cleanTransferListener();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, AsyncEmitter.BackpressureMode.DROP);
```

Comment: you need to release transObs's Listener in dispose() method. And I guess it's better to use a Completable since you don't care about the onNext()s.