# How to create Observable by call back method in rxjava?

Tags: android, rx-java

Some time I have exiting method or callback, then I want create a data flow by parameter of these methods.

For a example, I want watch onKeyDown() callback, and do some work when user input some specfic numbers like "1,2,3,4"，what should I do if I use RxJava?

Comment: answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43164771/3903847  
how to bridge between callback world and RxJava

Comment: another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41870888/697313