# CustomObservable vs Observable.create()?

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm working on wrapping listeners into Observables. Normally we use `Observable.create()` to wrap that but there are libraries prefer to use custom Observables and wrap things inside of it such as `RxBinding`, or even RxJava itself (from what my understanding, `operators` are basically create new Custom Observable to do operation inside of it).

So my questions are: 
what benefits we can get from Custom Observable? It's just lower overhead than `Observable.create()` since we don't generate another `ObservableCreate` to cover `ObservableSource` for us.

Which should I use for wrapping an existing Library into Rx Style (ex: Firebase)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41870888/697313

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy Not exactly. Actually I'm wondering why libs such as `RxBinding` use custom Observable instead of `Observable.create`

Comment: Libraries maximize code reuse, have their internal architecture/philosophy. In case you write a library with many wrapped interfaces you might invest time into developing and testing some biolerplate base classes, which might be more convenient for you to extend, than using generic `create`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating custom Observables offers lover overhead in some situations.

In RxJava 1.x, there is no benefit extending an `Observable` and using `Observable.create(OnSubscribe)` because they are practically the same. There is, however the benefit of creating an `Observable` for an intermediate operator than using `lift()` with a custom `Operator`. `Observable.create(Emitter, BackpressureStrategy)` adds overhead with the extra safeguard because people tend to find `create` first and practically reimplement `just()`, `range()` or `from()` with it before realizing it's unnecessary.

In RxJava 2.x, the default way is to extend `Observable` and the other types to add source/intermediate operators which is the lowest overhead there could be. The safeguarded creation methods are still there but with some small investment into understanding the protocol, you can avoid the allocation of extra objects due to `create()` by having an `Observer` or `Disposable` also implement the interfaces or extending a base class of the targeted external technology.

For example, this is how I wrote an adapter library for Java Swing and RxJava 2:

```
final class ActionEventObservable extends Observable<ActionEvent> {

    final AbstractButton widget;

    ActionEventObservable(AbstractButton widget) {
        this.widget = widget;
    }

    @Override 
    protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super ActionEvent> observer) {
        AbstractButton w = widget;
        ActionEventConsumer aec = new ActionEventConsumer(observer, w);
        observer.onSubscribe(aec);
        w.addActionListener(aec);
        if (aec.get() == null) {
            w.removeActionListener(aec);
        }
    }

    static final class ActionEventConsumer
            extends AbstractEventConsumer<ActionEvent, AbstractButton>
            implements ActionListener {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -3605206827474016488L;

        ActionEventConsumer(Observer<? super ActionEvent> actual, AbstractButton widget) {
            super(actual, widget);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            actual.onNext(e);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDispose(AbstractButton component) {
            component.removeActionListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Some Disposable management is hidden in a common `AbstractEventConsumer` class and the individual event handlers mostly have to implement the required `Listener` and call the appropriate remove method on dispose.

On a side note, most popular technologies may already have RxJava adapters you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever possible I would use library provided creation methods like: `generate`, `fromCallable` or `create`. There is no overhead in them. They take care of various housekeeping issues, which you can easily forget when writing your custom observable.

Unfortunately there are cases when you cannot use them, eg. when you need special scheduling. Before writing custom observable I would recommend looking into source code of `generate` or `create` library methods. Make sure you understand every bit of it, so you can do similar things in your observable.