# what is lifecycle of listeners inside ObservableOnSubscribe callback - Rxjava

Tags: android, performance, firebase-authentication, rx-java2

I've done an Rxjava wrrapper for firebase `signInWithCustomToken()` method, here is the code:

```
public Observable<AuthResult> signInWithCustomToken(String token) {
    return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<AuthResult>() {
      @Override public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<AuthResult> emitter) throws Exception {
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCustomToken(token)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
              @Override public void onSuccess(AuthResult result) {
                emitter.onNext(result);
              }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
              @Override public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                emitter.onError(e);
              }
            })
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
              @Override public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                emitter.onComplete();
              }
            });
      }
    });
  }
```

so I was wondering what is the lifecycle of the three listeners (`OnSuccessListener` - `OnFailureListener()` - `OnCompleteListener`) inside the Rx callback, Do they have the same lifecycle of the return Observable, in other words if I called `observable.dispose()`, will they be cleared from memory?

and I have another question sorry, is this the best way for modeling such a method in Rx way?

thank you in avance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my question, calling dispose() doesn't guarantee removing those listeners from memory. but there is a nice solution for this.
each time you create an Observable from listeners or callback make sure to setup a Cancellable and clear things there.

```
emitter.setCancellable(new Cancellable() {
  @Override
  public void cancel() throws Exception {
  //clean memory
 }
});
```

however the case with code mention in question, that firebase doesn't provide a method to clear those listeners in `signwithCustomToken()`. but other like DatabaseReference has removeListenr() method to clear things when canceling.

```
emitter.setCancellable(new Cancellable() {
  @Override
  public void cancel() throws Exception {
    databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do they have the same lifecycle of the return Observable, in other words if I called observable.dispose(), will they be cleared from memory?

No, you need to specify the disposable logic yourself, and there remove your listeners from `firebaseAuth`, you can do it using either `Emitter.setDisposable()` or `Emitter.setCancellable()`, if you will not supply it, then the `Observable` will merely untie the connection between the `Subscriber` and the `Observable` and will stop emit events, but the listeners will stay registered to `firebaseAuth` and memory leak might happen.

> and I have another question sorry, is this the best way for modeling such a method in Rx way?

using RxJava2 create methods is valid method for wrapping async callbacks methods. However, with RxJava2 the default way with lowest overhead is to extend `Observable` and use `Observer` methods to notify events/ register dispose callback. you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43659655/3903847).