# Binding an API callback to an RxJava Observable

Tags: java, system.reactive, rx-java, observable

I'm trying make a reactive application that listens to a network socket on a separate thread for prices and got a bit stumped with how exactly to construct the `Observable`. Much of the interfaces I have are constrained by the API I am using and therefore cannot change. I distilled what I am trying to do as a test below, but I can't see how to fill in the body of the `getPriceReactive()` method such that the prices are printed on the console by the subscriber (see the comment in the code).

```
public class PriceObservableTest {

   // This interface is defined externally and used by the API
   private interface ITickHandler {
       void priceReceived(double price);
   }

   // Stores the price (currently just one double for illustration)
   private class Tick {
       double price = Double.NaN;
   }

   // Implementation of handler called by API when it receives a price
   private class TickHandler implements ITickHandler {
       private final Tick tick;

       TickHandler() { this.tick = new Tick(); }

       @Override public void priceReceived(double x) { tick.price = x; }
   }

   // This class emulates the API delivering prices from the socket
   private class PriceSource {
      private final Thread thread;

      PriceSource(final ITickHandler handler) {
          thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
              final Random r = new Random();
              @Override public void run() {
                  while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                      try {
                          Thread.sleep(100);
                          handler.priceReceived(r.nextDouble() * 100);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          break;
                      }
                  }
                  System.out.println("Price thread closed");
              }
         });
      }

      void subscribe() { thread.start(); }

      void unsubscribe() { thread.interrupt(); }
  }

  @Test
  public void simpleTest() throws Exception {

      final ITickHandler handler = new TickHandler();

      // Simulate some prices received periodically from a socket
      PriceSource prices = new PriceSource(handler);

      Observable<Tick> reactive = getPriceReactive(handler);

      reactive.subscribe(new Subscriber<Tick>() {
          @Override public void onCompleted() { }
          @Override public void onError(Throwable e) { }
          @Override public void onNext(Tick tick) {
              System.out.println("Received price: " + tick.price);
          }});

      // Observe prices for 1 second. The subscriber should print them to console
      prices.subscribe();
      Thread.sleep(1000); 
      prices.unsubscribe();
   }

   // Returns an observable that reacts to price changes
   private Observable<Tick> getPriceReactive(ITickHandler handler) {
       return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Tick>() {
           @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Tick> subscriber) {

              // How to call subscriber.onNext() whenever
              // priceReceived() is called with a new price?

           }
       });
   }
}
```

Somehow `subscriber.onNext()` needs to be called whenever the API calls `priceReceived()`, but I can't quite see how to achieve this. Of course I could store a reference to the subscriber in the `TickHandler` but this kind of defeats the purpose of having an `Observable`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transition to `Observable` in `ITickHandler` implementation. You are not controlling the subscriber(s) but the publisher

```
private class TickHandler implements ITickHandler {
   private final Tick tick;
   private final PublishSubject<Tick> priceSubject;

  TickHandler() { 
       this.tick = new Tick(); 
       this.priceSubject = PublishSubject.create();
   }

   @Override public void priceReceived(double x)
   { 
        tick.price = x; 
        priceSubject.onNext(tick);
   }

   public Observable<Tick> priceReceivedObservable()
   {
       return priceSubject.asObservable();   
   }
}
```

And you can use it in your tests like:

```
final ITickHandler handler = new TickHandler();
PriceSource prices = new PriceSource(handler);

handler.priceReceivedObservable()
       .subscribe(new Subscriber<Tick>() {
          @Override public void onCompleted() { }
          @Override public void onError(Throwable e) { }
          @Override public void onNext(Tick tick) {
              System.out.println("Received price: " + tick.price);
          }});
```

I warn you, it's not tested since I don't do a lot of Java :)

Comment: Interesting use of subject, but I'm a bit suspicious of them since the rx docs seem to suggest they should only be needed in rare cases. Actually, it turns out a very similar question was asked already, the solution does not involve subjects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552598/creating-observable-from-normal-java-events/

Comment: @ScarletPumpernickel I wouldn't say the question or any of the answers are relevant to your question (unless you want to pollute your code with custom events). I would also say that this is a proper use case for a `Subject`

Comment: I will +1 the use of subjects - they are excellent whenever you want to drive an Observable with external events, possibly not entirely under your control. Observable.create() also works, but it's going to be a bit more cumbersome, and you will need to handle (or prevent)  multiple subscriptions.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos even with `Observable.Create` you'd have to use either a `Subject` or an event to transfer the API call to an `Observable`, right?

Comment: No necessarily - when the callback in the create() runs, you have access to a Subscriber; you can drive that manually at that point.